# Calling API of another laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.1

I have two laravel projects.
One of them has an API

I am trying to get data using the API.

```
public function getSyncOrders() {
    $orders = Invoice::where('status', 0)->get();
    return response()->json([
        'data' => [
            'orders'                => $orders
        ]
    ], 200);      
}
```

I am trying to fetch data in the other laravel project.

```
public function syncOrders() {
    if(auth()->check()){
        Order::truncate();

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://project1.net/api/sync-orders",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 600,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            //echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
    }
    else{
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

But I get the error :

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'project2.invoice' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `invoice`
>   where `status` = 0)

Project 1 has table `invoice` in database while project 2 has table `orders` in database.

If I use the url `http://project1.net/api/sync-orders` in browser, it returns data.

I need help to fix the curl request so that project 2 doesn't execute code and search in its own database but instead get the data from the API.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this issue? 
I am having the same problem and I wouldn't like to add a second connection in my laravel configs

Comment: @JaimeNoelAlvarezLuna Yes, I didn't have to add a second connection, just had to rename the key in env and config for one of the two projects, or just directly specify db name in config. Usually renaming in env and config is a better option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing `DB_DATABASE` in `config` and `env` to `DB_DATABASE2` for project 2 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is a cache problem, please run these commands in order to fix your problems:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize
```

Thanks to [Sergio Chamorro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10221483/sergio-chamorro) for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's so weird that you are seeing that error. If you insist on doing the job only using curl, maybe it'd be better if you provide more details.

But I recommend start using [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html)

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.0
```

then your code will become like this:

```
public function syncOrders() {
    if(auth()->check()){
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://project1.net/api/']);
        $response = $client->get('sync-orders')->send();
        dd($response->getBody(), $response); // you can do whatever you want with $response
    }

    return redirect('/');

}
```

Comment: What more details do you need?

Comment: What servers project1.net & project2 are pointing to? are they on the same server? are you sure that you are getting the error while you are calling the second project's `syncOrders`? it's impossible for the `syncOrders` function to throw the error you said `Table 'project2.invoice' doesn't exist` because there `invoice` is not mentioned in it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in this url (http://project1.net/api/sync-orders) , Invoice model is connected to 'project2' database.

So in your .env file **or** your config in (config/database.php) change **database** to `project1`