# Laravel API - http client - database error

Tags: laravel, laravel-http-client

I have an API endpoint on domain-1

```
Route::get('users', [UserApiController::class, 'index'])
```

and I try to retrieve the data from domain-2.
I use the HTTP client to execute a request on the API route.

```
Http::get('http://www.domain-1/api/users')
```

But the request sends me back a Base table or view not found: 1146 the table 'domain-2-db.users' does not exists
-> trying to find a table on the domain-2 database instead of performing the request on the domain-1-db

I tried hitting the API endpoint

```
http://www.domain-1/api/users
```

directly in the browser or with Postman, and I can access the data.
I also tried to submit a form from the domain-2, and I retrieve the data.

The error only occurs with the HTTP client.

May be that's pretty obvious, but I can't figure out what's the issue and how to fix it.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? If such an error is thrown, that is usually not related to the usage of an API or the HttpClient - but related to the table not existing?

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, i can perform a test with a form in a template from domain-2, and i can retrive the data, the error occurs only with an HTTP request. The table exist on the domain-1 project

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If you open `http://www.domain-1/api/users` in your browser, does this yield the same error? What did you try to check why this happens?

Comment: I have edited my post with the tests i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response came from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/53803441/10309333

The solution was to change the DB_DATABASE const name from the env file